# Is SASS/SCSS a way to make OOCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, oocss

i know SASS/SCSS and I know whats object oriented, but can I say that SASS is a way to make CSS object oriented? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting question as SASS/SCSS doesn't exactly determine the ability to make CSS object oriented. The CSS you write will. As you know it is simply a layer to pre compile CSS.

You could definitely and rightly so state that by using SASS it makes it easier to create object oriented-like css. It definitely helps as you can individualise classes into files, extend, include etc. and you can import them which helps in creating a closer to modular environment than regular CSS provides.

As SASS compiles to CSS, you really could achieve the same Object Oriented classes without it. But it *may* help you organise the *objects*.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not really object oriented, but you can use some functions like other progrmamming languages.

- variable
- nesting
- mixin (function)
- opearators (+ - * /)

These help you easier to reuse and maintain css code